# How do I handle the system windows with Python on Windows OS?

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, wxpython, selenium-chromedriver

With Selenium Webdriver, I have to upload some files on a website but since the pop-up window for browsing the file location is handled by the operating system and not the browser, I cannot automate that part with Selenium.

So I want to know which framework or module I need to use to work with system windows of Windows OS. Can tkInter or wxPython be used for this?

My script will be used on Windows 7, 8 & 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can upload files without interacting with upload prompt pop-ups.

To be able to handle file upload with `selenium` you should send path to file to appropriate input field **without clicking on "Upload" button**. Try following:

```
path_to_file = 'C:\\Files\\path\\to\\file'  # use your specific path instead
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]').send_keys(path_to_file)
```

P.S. Let me know if this code doesn't work as you expect

Comment: The HTML tag is <a> and not <input> so that does not work.

Comment: Can you check again? `<a>` is a link. I'm quite sure that it cannot be used as element for file upload handling. Or just try to implement my code :) Also add `HTML` code for target element

Answer (score 0):

You can call autoit3 framework from Python even to open the File Open dialog and fill in the values and press OK or do whatever with the windows. Autoit3 has a dll that can be loaded and called using ctypes. That's what I did in one or 2 projects.

If I understand your question correctly, wxpython or tk won't help you. They can be used to make the windowed UI, not to control other programs.